# MongoDB - Problems with paginating records using a score sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, pagination

Let's say I have 3 records with these scores:

```
{_id: 3, score: 0}, {_id: 20, score: 2.5}, {_id: 1, score: 0}
```

Right now, I query it in this way

```
Model.find({
  score: {$lt: lastScore}
})
.sort({score: -1})
.limit(2)
```

*lastScore* is the score of the latest record found from this query. In this way, in the next iteration, I can get the following page of records, without including the previous records.

But there is a huge problem, let's see what will happen with this query:

First of all, the 2 records sorted by score will be taken: `{_id: 20, score: 2.5}, {_id: 3, score: 0}`. So, *lastScore* will be equal to 0. If you see above, I use `score: {$lt: lastScore}`, so in the next iteration, the latest record will not be found (0 is not minor than *lastScore*, which also is 0). This problem happen with all the records that have the same score..

Do you have some proposals on how to implement pagination, using the sorting by score with Mongoose ?

PS: quick solution would be to use the .skip() method but it is not really good with big collections and I need a scalable solution

Comment: I think your only option is to use `$lte` (less than or equal), but that might still not get the results you are looking for, `.skip()` will most likely be your best solution

Comment: `$lte` will help you.

Comment: Unfortunally $lte is not a viable solution. Imagine hundred of records with score 0, $lte will only get the first 2 (there is `.limit(2)`) because _lastScore_ will be always 0, and also it will include the previous records

Comment: What do you exactly want then? Please give a practical use case example as that will help me to understand your problem.

Comment: I have to implement a feed like the facebook news feed, which should have the infinite scrolling. For now, I'm using the .skip() method of Mongo, but it's not a good solution as it will leak as the collection will gets bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endend up using the .skip() method, no other solutions for now.